# Creating empty list and adding items to this newly created list in Earth Engine Code Editor?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I have tried something like this:

```
var empty_list = ee.List([])
```

However, when adding items to this list, it returns an empty list regardless.

Here is a code snippet. Note that "col_list" is a variable representing an image collection.

```
var list = ee.List([]);

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){

  var img = ee.Image(col_list.get(i));

  var dictionary = ee.Dictionary({
    coords: img.geometry().getInfo()["coordinates"],
    landsat_id: img.get('LANDSAT_ID'),
    satellite: img.get('SATELLITE'),
    sensing_time: img.get('SENSING_TIME'),
    system_index: img.get('system:index')
  });

  var feature = ee.Feature(null, dictionary);
  var list = list.add(feature);
}
```

This definitely looks wrong but I am not sure how else to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Nishanta answer is correct if you think in JavaScript, I would like to show you how to do it in the *Earth Engine way*, which I think is better for this.

```js
var list = col_list.iterate(function(img, first){
  // cast variables
  img = ee.Image(img)
  first = ee.List(first)
  // same as before but without `getInfo`
  var dictionary = ee.Dictionary({
    coords: img.geometry().coordinates(),
    landsat_id: img.get('LANDSAT_ID'),
    satellite: img.get('SATELLITE'),
    sensing_time: img.get('SENSING_TIME'),
    system_index: img.get('system:index')
  });

  var feature = ee.Feature(null, dictionary);
  return first.add(feature)
}, ee.List([]))

// cast the result to ee.List
list = ee.List(list)

print(list)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are redefining the variable list within your loop so the scope of that variable extends only within the loop and the **list** variable outside the loop is never getting updated. It should be fixed by removing the "var" in front of **list** WITHIN the loop. (line 12 in code below)

```
var list = ee.List([]);
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  var img = ee.Image(col_list.get(i));
  var dictionary = ee.Dictionary({
    coords: img.geometry().getInfo()["coordinates"],
    landsat_id: img.get('LANDSAT_ID'),
    satellite: img.get('SATELLITE'),
    sensing_time: img.get('SENSING_TIME'),
    system_index: img.get('system:index')
  });
  var feature = ee.Feature(null, dictionary);
  list = list.add(feature);
}
```